# Can't Run Assault Cube

Tags: graphics, games

I installed assault cube from the Software centre and it just opens for half a second and closes. When i run in it from the terminal, this is what i get -

```
d@d-platform:~$ assaultcube
Using home directory: /home/d/.assaultcube_v1.104
current locale: en_IN
init: sdl
init: net
init: world
init: video: sdl
init: video: mode
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  129 (XFree86-VidModeExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  10 (XF86VidModeSwitchToMode)
  Value in failed request:  0xb3
  Serial number of failed request:  131
  Current serial number in output stream:  133
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev` by `sudo apt-get install x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev` and then retry launching the game.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it was still not working. Then I tried running in windowed mode (-t) and it worked. Any ideas what the issue might be with my computer?

Comment: well, from the error message you provided previously, it looks like the header file for X protocol (`/usr/include/X11/Xproto.h`) lacks the operation performed with `opcode 129` which is `XFree86-VidModeExtension`, so I suggested you to install that package.

Answer (score 0):

With a clue from here I was able to fix mine. open it up with the -t option from the terminal, then go to options and go to display, there you uncheck v-sync. after that you can set it to full screen and apply. it works. even works after closing and opening the program.